# LINQ query with Joins and aggregate

Tags: linq

I would request someone to please check whether my following **LINQ query** with **4 tables joins** and **group by** is logically correct? Is it the correct way write LINQ query for 4 tables join and Group by clause?

**My second point:**

If I comment line `TotalTime = tstGroup.Sum(x=>x.Duration)`, it works fine.

But, If I uncomment this line it say the following exception.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
```

What is wrong? Please comment

**Tables**

```
Table A: Id, FirstName
Table B: Id, AId(Table A FK)
Table C: Id, BId(Table B FK), Duration
Table D: Id, AId(Table A FK). Description


           tstData= (from a in _context.A
                            join b in _context.B on a.Id equals b.AId
                            join c in _context.C on b.Id equals c.BId
                            join d in _context.D on a.Id equals d.AId

                            group c by new { a= a, b= b, d= d} into tstGroup
                            select new myobj
                            {
                                FirstName= tstGroup.Key.a.FirstName,
                                Description= tstGroup.Key.d.description,
                                TotalTime = tstGroup.Sum(x=>x.Duration),

                            }).ToList();
```

**Modified LINQ.** 
Do you feel it is correct now? Removed multiple group clauses.

```
           tstData= (from a in _context.A
                            join b in _context.B on a.Id equals b.AId
                            join c in _context.C on b.Id equals c.BId
                            join d in _context.D on a.Id equals d.AId

                            group c by new { c.Id, c.Duration, d.Name, a.FirstName} into tstGroup
                            select new myobj
                            {
                                FirstName= tstGroup.Key.FirstName,
                                Description= tstGroup.Key.description,
                                TotalTime = tstGroup.Sum(x=>x.Duration),

                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: There should be an inner exception there. Also, grouping by all individual items is useless: each group will have one row. Maybe you should tell what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes there is an exception and i have mentioned it in my question.. I am trying to sum the duration from table C, read the firstname from table A and read description from table D. All 4 tables are linked with each other as i mentioned in my question.

Comment: **inner** exception.

Comment: Yes there is an inner exception. Did you understand my requirement in my above comments?

Comment: If the tables are linked as you say, your code isn't even functional since you're using `a.Id == b.Id`, though you say `b.JobId` should be the FK to a.

Comment: Its just a type mistake since i did not expose orignal tables. I have updated my question. please recheck. Till Joins part it is working i believe, Problem is i am not sure about grouping and then reading out value. thanks

Comment: Hi Gert Arnold what is reason for exeption? How i can remove it?

Comment: Well, if I knew the inner exception...

Comment: Just a guess here, but does EF support summing `TimeSpan`s (assuming that's what `c.Duration` is)? It would really help if you could include the details of the inner exception so we can understand what's wrong.

Comment: Gert Arnold, I just see inner exception message in my browser. How would you have written LINQ query based on my requirement? May be your little psedocode gives an idea how i can write this query. I am sure as you said My grouping way is totaly wrong. How you would have written this 4 table join with group by?

Comment: I'm still a long way from trying to look into this. For one, I would use navigation properties in stead of joining explicitly. But I don't know your class model nor the multiplicity of associations. If for instance C:D is a 1:n association, grouping is useless.

Comment: Table C has navigation property for Table B. Table B has navigation property to Table A. Table A has navigation Property for Table D.

Comment: Dude, just include the inner exception text instead of guessing around.

Comment: Avish, very simple question how would you write join of 3/4 tables and then do some aggregate?

Comment: You'll get incorrect results. A will be multiplied because it has multiple D's. For all of these duplicates you will sum durations. If you want durations per A, D should be removed from the equation.

Comment: Please see my updated question. i updated my query based on your comments.

Comment: you're grouping by the duration, so you can't sum it.

Comment: @ DLeh , I think i am reaching close to solution. Should i take out only "c.Duration," from my group and rest of the parameters fine?

Comment: Will sum work correctly if i return .ToList()?

Comment: Hi, thank you everyone for sharing your thoughts. I have resolved the problem using navigation properties as Gert mentioned above. If anyone come to this question by searching and want to know how to resolve it just comment here.